# Add Images from Array to ImageView

Tags: ios, xcode, uigraphicscontext

Im trying to do an undo function for my paint app in iOS. My approach is that after each drawing (lines, straight lines, squares, circles), the drawing will be added to an array so that I can pop/remove the lastObjectIndex of the array on undo and then repaint the contents of the array to the image view. I am using an NSMutableArray and UIImage and use UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext. My question is, how can I display all the image arrays into one UIImageView?

Here is my code:

```
imgArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

UIImage *tempImg = [[UIImage alloc] init];
tempImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
[imgArray addObject:tempImg];

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mainImage.frame.size);
[mainImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
[tempImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:opacity];
mainImage.image = tempImg; //UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
tempImage.image = nil;
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: what do you mean by "display all"? did you call [yourUIImageView setImage:[imgArray objectAtIndex:index]]?

Comment: Why you don't use multi instances of UIImaveView (one for each UIImage) ?
This way should be easy to implement and you can have more interaction on each object, like change the size or frame.

But if you want to draw all images in just one UIImageView you can for example use multi layer and draw one image in each layer or implement an algoritm to draw the images in draw method.

Comment: @boreas: Yes Ive tried that but only the last drawing is shown and recent drawings on the UIImageView are cleared.

Comment: @Zasuk: Using multiple instances might not be the answer for me since this is a drawing app.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, your model is a graphics app with say an initial background and then a stack of layers, each layer having an object or objects on it.

If so, then your saved images would represent this stack. You could keep a temp image representing n-1 of the stack, then the current image, to make rendering go faster. In fact, what I would do is have the temp image in a view and the current active object in a different view overtop the temp one.

When you have undo, you can first just erase the current active object. A second undo would then force you to re-render the temp pict by starting at image 0 and drawing each layer over the base image. What makes this work is that each layer is transparent except for the drawn bits.

To create the temp image, I'd use a bitmap context and apply the layers in code, unsure if the Quartz methods will do this for you or not (they well may).